# OpenBEAGLE - PACC installation missing files

Tags: cmake, installation, cmake-gui

I'm using OpenBEAGLE (http://chgagne.github.io/beagle/) as a genetic algorithm framework for my master thesis and I'm trying to install PACC (which is required beforehand) but I'm struggling a lot do accomplish it. There are some missing files such as the ZLIB library and pthread.h header file which I have no idea what to do with them. Already downloaded both and put them on their respective path folders where Cmake looks for them but Cmake always give me these errors.

```
`++ Building in release mode (default)...
++ Building static library (default on Microsoft Visual C++)
++ Building static library
++ Windows found...
++ NSIS installer creator not found
++ System configuration detection...
++ Looking for ZLib library...
Could NOT find ZLIB (missing: ZLIB_LIBRARY) (found version "1.2.11")
++ Cannot find ZLib, socket compression disabled...
++ Looking for threads libraries...
Looking for pthread.h
Looking for pthread.h - not found
Found Threads: TRUE  
++ Using Windows threads...
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:183 (check_include_files):
Unknown CMake command "check_include_files"`
```

Does someone have any idea how to overcome these errors? Btw, I'm using OS 64-bit Windows 10.

Thanks in advance. André

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Here we expect log messages described the problem to be in the question post itself **as text**, not linked as images. Fix this by [edit]ing the question.

Comment: `Could NOT find ZLIB (missing: ZLIB_LIBRARY) (found version "1.2.11")` means that you have include files (`.h`), but don't have a library (`.lib`/`.dll`). `Looking for pthread.h - not found` means that the header is not found, but it is normal for Windows, thread library is correctly detected - `Found Threads: TRUE`. `Unknown CMake command "check_include_files"` means that a problem in the package you are currently configuring, report this problem into its bugtracker.

Answer (score 0):

When you try to install PACC make sure you have ZLIB. If not, you can download it from https://zlib.net. Then save the ZLIB folder in your program files and try to compile PACC with Cmake. If Cmake doesn't find ZLIB (you will see the error "PACC_LIB_FOUND_PATH = NOTFOUND") make sure that you specify in Cmake the path for the variable "PACC_LIB_FOUND_PATH" where the header file zlib.h is.

After this you are good to configure OpenBEAGLE. Here make sure that you specify the path for the file config.h which you can find in the folder "...\include\PACC" after you have tried to compile it once.